# What should my tablet be charging at?

Tags: charging, tablet, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I just got a RocketFish USB wall charger with 2.4 amps and 5 Volts. The charge meter that I am using is telling me that it is charging at 50 mA. I also notice that when I try to turn it off to charge, it will have a red 'X' on the battery icon when I turn it back on while it wasn't there.
Is it safe to be charging it with this charger? Should it be charging this slowly?
The charger model number is RF-AC1U2N.

Answer (score 0):

Although charging it slowly will not have a problem, in your case your shouldn't as it is giving a 'x' mark..But you should take care you're not using your tab while charging. Since the charging process is slower than normal, if you simultaneously plug in and use the tab, the battery might deteriorate. Also use quality charger.